# Need a Reason and what is the difference between these two things?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(100 + 100 +"Simplilearn");   
System.out.println("E-Learning Company" + 100 + 100);
```

output:

```
200Simplilearn  
E-Learning Company100100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Javas behavoiur is to interprete your given values.

Your cases:
1)

```
System.out.println(100 + 100 +"Simplilearn");
```

100 is an integer, so Java interprets the "+" as arihmetic operator.
100 + 100 equals 200.

The next "+" cant be of arithmetic type, because of "Simplilearn" wich is an String.

2)

```
System.out.println("E-Learning Company" + 100 + 100);
```

If you give Java an String at first (same is if you youse this as variable value), Java interprets the whole line as String.
This is because "+" can´t be an arithmetic type, when the previous is a string.

So for Java your Output equals "E-Learning Company100100".